# disable/enable buttons

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm working in ASP .Net. I need to be able to click a button, disable it, have the code behind kick in and execute some functions and once they are done, enable the button again. There is no postback taking place per say in this project as we are using an UpdatePanel. About as far as I've been able to get successfully is using this syntax to disable it on the code behind Page_Load function:

```
btnConnect.Attributes.Add("onClick", "document.body.style.cursor = 'wait';this.disabled = true;" + ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(btnConnect, string.Empty) + ";");
```

This disables the button and allows the code behind to execute. I just can't figure out how to re-enable the button once the functions that run in the code behind are done. Is there a way to capture when the code behind is done?

Comment: Is the button inside the UpdatePanel as well? Then it should be rewritten when the async postback returns. (This is just an assumption, which is why I write this as a comment instead of an answer.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a timeout approach after the disable:

```
var that = this; //pointer to button
window.setTimeout(function() { document.body.style.cursor = '';that.disabled = false; }, 1000);
```

This approach can be useful to prevent a double-postback too.

Or the update panel finishes it fires the Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.endRequest event.  Add an event handler to reenable the button in there as another alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to use jQuery instead? Consider a flow like this:

- on click, disable button
- call/POST to an ASP.NET URL as needed
- re-enable the button when the URL call returns. Update page elements, redirect, alert as needed.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to above...

Yes, you are using an UpdatePanel, but a PostBack is occurring.

So, in your submit button event, after successful processing is complete, remove the attribute for onClick you added above, have you tried to enable the button in the code behind and then issue an Update() on your UpdatePanel?